Solving PDE with conditions $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$, $u = h$
We consider the Cauchy problem associated to the linear PDE
$$x\left(x^2 + y^2\right)u_x + 2y^2\left(xu_x + yu_y - u\right) = 0,$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = a^2, \text{ } u = h.$$
We must study the existence of solution in a neighbourhood of each point of the given curve and determine the solution.
I know the transversality condition which tells you the existence of unique solution in a neighbourhood of a point, but I don't know how to apply it in this case, so I started manipulating the equation in order to get
$$x\left(x^2 + 3y^2\right)u_x + 2y^3 u_y = 2y^2 u.$$
However, I'm not able to continue this way.
Also I have observed that I could take polar coordinates because of the first condition, but I don't really know.

Do you know the method of characteristics? Applying it leads to the general solution of the PDE : $$u(x,y)=y;F\left( y+\frac{y^3}{x^2}\right)$$ with arbitrary function $F$. Then determine $F$ according to the specified condition.

@JJacquelin I tried but I get $F\left(a\dfrac{\sin(t)}{\cos^2(t)}\right) = \dfrac{h}{a\sin(t)}$ with $(x, y) = \left(a\cos(t), a\sin(t)\right)$, I don't know what to do

Sorry without the details of your calculus one cannot check it and see where you are stuck. Can you edit it in the question (not in comment).
